# Тире перед частицей «это»

Tags: пунктуация, тире, связка

> Все, что я знаю, (—) это ничего!

Интересует такой вопрос: верно ли поставлено тире в приведенном выше предложении?

---

Из справочника по правописанию и стилистике: "Тире ставится перед словами *это, это есть, вот, вот значит, это значит,* присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему".

---

В правиле не оговаривается, какими частями речи должны быть выражены подлежащее и сказуемое, значит, судя по всему, тире ставиться должно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Все, что я знаю, — это** [то, что я] **ничего** [не знаю] **!***

Считаю, что тире обязательно (да и интонация соответствующая).
Если в справочнике не сказано, какими частями речи должны быть выражены главные члены предложения, значит – любыми. А "[**Грамота.ру**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172)" категорична:

> **6.**  Если в составе сказуемого есть указательные слова ЭТО, ВОТ или ЗНАЧИТ, тире надо ставить перед ними всегда, вне зависимости от того, какой частью речи выражены главные члены предложения. Например: *Париж – это столица Франции; Понять – значит простить; Все прошедшее, настоящее, будущее – это мы, а не слепая сила стихий* (Горький).

Comment: Расшифровка интересная, но это уже другой вариант. Просто результат совпадает. В исходном варианте указывается, что он ничего не знает, даже не знает то, что он ничего не знает. Ну и в вашем варианте логическая петля получается: если он знает, что он ничего не знает, то он уже хоть что-то знает.